# How to receive JSON using AJAX, node.js, and mysql

Tags: php, jquery, json, node.js, ajax

So, in my project's homepage, I use jquery's ajax to retrieve  JSON data and manipulate it as I need. This is done with this code snippet as my PHP api, and my homepage is written javascript and jquery (ajax). Also I use apache server in this project.

```
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "db_name";
$user = "root";
$pass = "password";

try {

  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname}", $user, $pass);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

} catch (Exception $e) {

  echo $e->getMessage();
}




$sql = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if (count($row) > 0) {
    $myJSON = json_encode($row);
    echo $myJSON;
} else {
    echo "No results found...";
}


?>
```

Now I am learning Node.js. And I am wanting to create the same api in a .js file using node.js and the 'mysql' module. Here is what I have so far...

```
var mysql = require('mysql');


// CONNECTIONION
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "password",
  database: "db_name"
});


// ERROR HANDLING
con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");


  // QUERY
  con.query("SELECT * FROM table_name", function(err, result, fields) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    };
    console.log(results);
  });//query close


});//connect close
```

So, how can I "echo" the json retrieved from database like I can in PHP. Again, I am trying to retrieve this using jquery ajax...

Help solving this would be much appreciated...

Comment: What does the given code and what is missing? Why did you create a callback with the parameter `result` and print a parameter calls `results`?

Comment: Ok, simple typo. This type was not in my original code. So still need answers. Thanks...

Comment: just pass the json to res.send method

Comment: @AlokDeshwal Can you explain exactly what you mean? Pass the 'result' in my query callback to the 'res', OR in my node.js server file? Which I believe I am doing here: else if (req.url.match(/.js$/)) {

    fs.readFile("./public/api.js", "UTF-8", function(error, data) {
      res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/json"});
      res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
      console.log(data);
    }

Comment: If you are using an HTTP server-side module named `express.js`, what you can do is utilize one of their methods call `response.json(result)` to respond with your AJAX call from the client side